# For Each... Loop not working

Tags: vbscript

I'm working on incorporating VBScript scripts in my HTML. Basically what I am doing now is having some input boxes appear on page load that asks the user to input four colours which are stored in an array. Later I am having the colours displayed on the page using a function I created. The function works like it is supposed to when I call it for every individual element of the array but my `For Each` loop doesn't do anything.

Here is the code that collects the colour information from the user:

```
Option Explicit
Dim colour(4)

colour(0) = Inputbox("Colour number 1")
Msgbox("The colour you entered is: " & colour(0))
colour(1) = Inputbox("Colour number 2")
Msgbox("The colour you entered is: " & colour(1))
colour(2) = Inputbox("Colour number 3")
Msgbox("The colour you entered is: " & colour(2))
colour(3) = Inputbox("Colour number 4")
Msgbox("The colour you entered is: " & colour(3))
```

This is the script I later call on to display those colours on the page, without the loop, that does exactly what I want it to:

```
Function printText(words)
    document.write("<h3 class='bodyheader'>Let's add the text '" & words & _
        "' to our website</h3>")
End Function

printText(colour(0))
printText(colour(1))
printText(colour(2))
printText(colour(3))
```

When I implement my `For Each` loop I don't get any kind of output at all, that area of the page remains blank. The error I get is

> illegal assignment: 'element'

```
Function printText(words)
    document.write("<h3 class='bodyheader'>Let's add the text '" & words & _
        "' to our website</h3>")
End Function

For Each element In colour
    printText(colour(element))
Next
```

Is something wrong with my syntax in the loop or is it another issue that I'm missing?

Comment: when you use for each, you do not use subscript for your array, with for each you are looping through each element of the array, and "element" variable in your case is a complete object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use:

```
For Each elm In colour
    printText(elm)
Next
```

or use:

```
For i=0 To UBound(colour)
    printText(colour(i))
Next
```

Comment: Using the first method I still receive the "illegal assignment: 'element'" error and using the second method I receive an "Object required: 'colour'" error. Any idea why that would be? It allows me to call on colour to print individually so it seems weird that using the loop would make a difference unless I'm just missing something here.

Comment: Perhaps "element" is a reserved word in VBScript? I replaced it with "elm". Try it now

Comment: As far as the other error, are you declaring your array in the same file?

Comment: The first method worked after changing to "elm". Thank you! As for the second method... The array is being declared only a few lines above this code.

Comment: You might need to declare "elm" as well: Dim elm

Comment: @MareenaW You have `Option Explicit` set so all variables have to be declared, with the second method did you `Dim i`?

Comment: I did not! That fixed it for me. Thanks everyone!!